# How to make Plugin-DataSource Layers Editable in ArcMap(Arcobjects)

Tags: arcobjects, .net

The .Net samples of the developer kit for ArcGis contains an [example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001t4000000), that shows how a custom data source([Plugin Data Source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Plug_in_data_sources/000100000003000000/)) can be added as a layer in ArcMap. It is done by implementing interfaces like `IPlugInCursorHelper`,`IPlugInWorkspaceFactoryHelper` etc...It displays the contains of a text file(Points in the example) as a layer in the map. This is not editable as of now.

Would it be possible to make this layer editable using the ArcGis editing tools by implementing some interfaces? In that case, what would be the interfaces that i would need to look at implementing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, plug-in data sources are **read-only**.

See [Plug-in data sources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000003000000), section *Comparison of custom data source implementations*.